# How to Add Dynamic Price in Magento for Vegetables

Tags: php, magento

How to add dynamic pricing in magento when we select the available quantity from the drop down menu.
here is an [Example](http://www.yoursabjiwala.com/vegetables/potato-new-2902.html)

So, by default what i want is that it should display the price of 1 kg and then when we select other options from the quantity it will alter the prices.
So, by default it must show the price of 1 kg and then when modify it will show the altered prices. 
Follow the example above.

Comment: I've sorted out the bottom logo problem what i want to know that how to do this : http://www.yoursabjiwala.com/vegetables/common/desitomato.html

Open this url and you will see that it will show the base price of the product but, when he select the Qty* which provides the custom option of the product it alters the actual price where as in Sahar template MAGENTO it adds up the price to the actual price 
What i want 
actual price <- alter in price = new price
100 <- 250 gm 3.50 rs = total price 3.50
what is happening 
actual price + add price = new price 
100 <250 gm 3.50 rs = total price 103.50

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a custom option for that product with dropdown type and provide the price for each value.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I've already done that but the problem is that, the custom values are getting added to the actual price.
What i want to do is that when someone land on a particular vegetable 
he can see the price of 1 kg of that item then he can modify that according to him

Comment: Make the 1kg price default for your custom option.

Comment: how to make that as a default price

Comment: Are you sure the price of custom option is added to the product actual price at the begining.I don't think so. It only changes when you select any custom option.Please check once again..

Comment: I've added the actual price which is 100 rs.
and then i added custom prices according to weight ..
but it shows 
250 mg + 2 rs 
which means that it is adding the price to the actual menu 
[link](http://mothersdaypoems2014.com/fusce-aliquam.html)  
but i want to make it like this 
http://www.yoursabjiwala.com/vegetables/common/desitomato.html